# Save a pdf, png, jpeg from webpage

Tags: php, jquery, html, pdf

I am developing a website for a charity, in which a user gets a receipt generated after making a donation.

My client wants the user to be able save this receipt as an image or pdf.

I have tried many API's and plugins, and even had my server admin install phantom.js, but I am unfamiliar with phantom, and couldn't get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Hi if you are building your site with PHP , than you can try this http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: I have that installed, but the documentation for it is very confusing. Do you have experience using it?

Comment: yes i have , what are you trying to achieve , can you post some codes , it would be helpful in understanding your requirements

Comment: how do i post a code snippet in here?

Comment: edit your question and update with your Code snippets that creates the receipt

Comment: Even that, doesn't do anything... I was just using it as a starting point.

Comment: Would wordpress block fpdf or mpdf?

Comment: do you have a screengrab of receipt , how you generating the receipt ?

Comment: I am generating 2 variables through cookies, the rest is static html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) php library to achieve this . FPDF is a free , php class which provide high level function and support many features like :

- Image Support(Jpeg,png)
- Color
- Links,
  Automatic page break and many more

[click here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/index.php) for quick tutorial.

Demo Code

```
<?php
 require('fpdf.php');

 $pdf = new FPDF();
 $pdf->AddPage();
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
 $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
 $pdf->Output();
?>
```

Don't forget to include fpdf.php

Comment: I am including the fpdf, but the function doesnt seem to be doing anything.

Comment: You would be doing something wrong.it should be working . check if there is any permission issue? try inspecting your php file.